# Jenkins CodeDeploy plugin errors

Tags: jenkins, plugins, jenkins-plugins, aws-code-deploy

So I am using the Jenkins codedeploy plugin to trigger an S3 bucket put of a zip file that is being pulled from my BitBucket repo so then CodeDeploy can deploy the revision to my EC2 instances. Some services via Jenkins succeed, but others fail with this log error. Note: the permissions on /tmp directory is 700.

I thought in order to avoid this warning error, "npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})" I could do npm install --no-optional but that clearly wasnt the reason why the build was not successful. Another good thing to note is that multiple services are using the same code deploy application and deployment group to install to the same instance. i.e each service is pulled from a different branch and pushed to the same instance via Code Deploy. I know it sounds super complex, but any help here is really appreciated!

```
Started by user xxxx
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Livit-Dev_Node
> git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
> git config remote.origin.url https://xxxx # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://xxxx
> git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials 
> git fetch --tags --progress xxxx+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
> git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/BRIDG-oauth-
implementation^{commit} # timeout=10
> git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin/BRIDG-oauth-
implementation^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision 0a2ebd5f1633483cea93d8a627870ac794a6556c 
(refs/remotes/origin/BRIDG-oauth-implementation)
> git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
> git checkout -f 0a2ebd5f1633483cea93d8a627870ac794a6556c
Commit message: "Merged in Test-Commit (pull request #22)"
> git rev-list --no-walk f7b3a6a9a26e413412bb5ddadec504da9500ba35 # 
timeout=10
[Livit-Dev_Node] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/jenkins6283232840818429990.sh
+ npm -v 5.6.0
+ npm install --no-optional
npm WARN livit-backend@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN livit-backend@1.0.0 No license field.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.3 
(node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform 
for fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: 
{"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

up to date in 6.31s
Zipping files into /tmp/#13-767184457865657281.zip
Failed CodeDeploy post-build step; exception follows.
Unable to get file permissions
hudson.os.PosixException: Unable to get file permissions null
at hudson.util.IOUtils.mode(IOUtils.java:133)
at hudson.util.io.ZipArchiver.visit(ZipArchiver.java:55)
at hudson.util.DirScanner.scanSingle(DirScanner.java:49)
at hudson.util.DirScanner$Glob.scan(DirScanner.java:131)
at hudson.FilePath$1.invoke(FilePath.java:473)
at hudson.FilePath$1.invoke(FilePath.java:469)
at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1009)
at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:987)
at hudson.FilePath.archive(FilePath.java:469)
at hudson.FilePath.zip(FilePath.java:456)
atcom.amazonaws.codedeploy.AWSCodeDeployPublisher.zipAndUpload(AWSCodeDeployPublisher.java:358)
at com.amazonaws.codedeploy.AWSCodeDeployPublisher.perform(AWSCodeDeployPublisher.java:230)
at hudson.tasks.BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.perform(BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.java:81)
at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:744)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:690)
at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:186)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:635)
at
```

Comment: Are you running as root? If not, you'll either need to change permissions on `/tmp` or copy the file somewhere else.

Comment: We had the same error caused by bad configuration of the AWS CodeDeploy Jenkins step. Can you post your configuration?

Comment: Any update on this? Is this resolved, I'm facing same issue. Thanks.